# BLE Device reconnect after powered off

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I powered off bluetooth device then `didDisconnectPeripheral` delegated is invoked.

When I power on the bluetooth device, which delegate function will be called?

Answer (score 0):

After disconnecting, you should restart scanning (`scanForPeripheralsWithServices`) for reconnect to the device.

[Here you have documentation to CBCentralManager.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html)

[In this link](http://hatemfaheem.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/how-would-you-scan-for-nearby-ble.html) you have a step by step tutorial to handle BLE Connection in swift.

Answer (score 0):

After you power on your BLE device in your app (if it is active) will ba called function

- centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:

[link to Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:)

Answer (score 0):

In `didDisconnectPeripheral` you can immediately call `connectPeripheral:options` to create a pending connection. Once the peripheral is powered on or comes back into range you will get a call to the `didConnectPeripheral` delegate method